# Djangoでcloud sqlに接続出来ない。

Tags: mysql, django, dialogflow

https://github.com/priyankavergadia/Django-Dialogflow-GoogleVisionAPI

↑のDjangoのチャットボットをリンク先のページのドキュメントを元に、動かそうとしているのですが、「Build and run the app locally」のところの、

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

を実行したところ下記エラーが出てきてしまいます。

```
    C:\Users\ellay\Django-Dialogflow-GoogleVisionAPI>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ellay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

インスタンス上のユーザー名・パスワード名が誤ってないかは何度も確認しているので、
問題ないはずなのですが、何度やってもこのエラーが突破できません。
様々検索した中で、

```
    C:\Users\ellay\Django-Dialogflow-GoogleVisionAPI>gcloud sql connect polls-instance2 --user=test
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.connect) HTTPError 400: The incoming request contained invalid data.
```

上記のsql接続テストでエラーが出ていることが原因なのではとも思っておりますが、
その先の原因特定・解決まで至っておりません。

またDjangoのsetting.py上の記載は下記になっています。

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/michatbot-250809:us-central1:polls-instance2',
            'USER': 'test',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'NAME': 'polls',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:

    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': 'polls',
            'USER': 'test',
            'PASSWORD': '',
        }
    }
# [END db_setup]
```

【環境】
■問題の発生した環境
・win10
・Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
・django 2.2.4
・MY SQL 第2世代5.7

調べるべきこと、エラーの可能性などどんな簡単な気付きだけでも結構ですのでアドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 参考: 英語版での関連質問 - [Django : mysql : 1045, "Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2443419)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"`のエラーは`test`というユーザーで`localhost`からMySQLにアクセスする権限が無いということです。

なので、以下のSQLを実行したら、このエラーは解消されるのではないかと思います。

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to test@localhost identified by '' with grant option;
```

"Access denied for user"でググるとたくさん情報が出てきます。

Comment: Koheiさん（@Kohei TAMURA　さん）　ご返信ありがとうございます。またご返答遅くなりまして申し訳ありません。教えていただいたコードを実行しても下記エラーが出てしまい、自己解決できないかと調べていましたがまだ解決できていません。`mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to test@localhost identified by '' with grant option;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by '' with grant option' at line 1`ちなみにmysqlの起動はrootユーザーからしか行えず、testユーザーで行おうとするとエラーが出ます。こういうところが何か影響があるのでしょうか。引き続き自己解決できないか、調査を続けてみます。

Comment: `C:\Users\ellay\Django-Dialogflow-GoogleVisionAPI>mysql -u root -p -S /cloudsql/michatbot-250809:us-central1:polls-instance2
Enter password: ************
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 27
Server version: 8.0.17 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.`

Comment: [https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy?hl=ja] こちらを参考にMySQLクライアントでCloudSQLインスタンスに接続をして調査をしてみたのですが、`mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
| test2            | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+` 一覧を調べたところcloudSQLのコンソール上で表示されるユーザー一覧とこちらの一覧が相違が出てしまい混乱してきました。cloudSQLユーザーとMySQLユーザーは異なるということなのでしょうか。SQLの基本から出直した方が良いかもと反省しております。。

Comment: 上のSQLの調査に関しては別質問を投稿することにしました。解決次第ベストアンサーをつけさせていただきます。申し訳ありません。

Comment: MySQL 8は構文が違うみたいですね。https://qiita.com/yamateion/items/5509484aaf1a02e9cc57

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。別で質問を立てたところcloudSQLはMySQL8を使えないはず、とコメントいただきました。ちょっと複雑になってきましたが、調べてみようと思います。

Comment: 解決いたしました。ありがとうございました。異なるSQLに接続されていたようで下記で解消いたしました。①MySQL8.0を過去インストールしていたようなので、それのアンインストール。②MySQL5.7のインストール　③あとは[https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy#start-mysql]に従い、サービスアカウントの設定からやり直すことでうまく疎通いたしました。